# Script fails at call to function

Tags: javascript, node.js, function

Please can someone help me with my script. It fails at the call to the function and im not sure why.

This is where i set up the arguments and call the function checkZone

```
// Get the geofence meta data and put it into a list
  const zones = geofence.map((geofence) => geofence.metadata);
  const geofence_list = zones[0];
  context.log("geofence_list = ",zones[0]);


  // Split location into lat long for point
  const latlong = location[0].value.split(",");
  //context.log("lat =", latlong[0]);
  //context.log("long =", latlong[1]);
  const point = [latlong[1], latlong[0]];
  context.log("point =", point);

  //Call the function insideZones to see if the device is in a geofence or not
  const insideZones = await checkZones(point, geofence_list);
```

This is the function

```
// This function checks if our device is inside any geofence
async function checkZones(point, geofence_list) {
  context.log('Running checkzones');
  const insideZones = [];
  // The line below gets all Polygon geofences that we may have.
  const polygons = geofence_list.filter((x) => x.geolocation.type === "Polygon");
  if (polygons.length) {
    // Here we check if our device is inside any Polygon geofence using our function above.
    for (const polygon of polygons) {
        if (insidePolygon(point,  polygon.geolocation.coordinates[0])){
            insideZones.push(polygon.event);
        }
    }
  }
  // The line below gets all Point (circle) geofences that we may have.
  const circles = geofence_list.filter((x) => x.geolocation.type === "Point");
  if (circles.length) {
    // Here we check if our device is inside any Point geofence using a third party library called geolib.
    for (const circle of circles) {
        if (geolib.isPointWithinRadius
           ({latitude:point[1],longitude: point[0] },
            {latitude: circle.geolocation.coordinates[0], longitude: circle.geolocation.coordinates[1] },
            circle.geolocation.radius)) { 
            insideZones.push(circle.event);
        }
    }
  }
  return insideZones;
}
```

Prints "geofence_list = " to console.
Prints "point =" to console.
Does not print "Running checkzones".

Console output

```
[2021-02-05 14:24:31] The geofence is :  inside_geo
[2021-02-05 14:24:31] {}
[2021-02-05 14:24:31] point =  18.3851121,-34.1258163
[2021-02-05 14:24:31] geofence_list =  {"color":"","event":"entering_zone","geolocation":{"coordinates":[-34.12429447233787,18.38298082351685],"radius":429.8821561214525,"type":"Point"},"id":"prUirTWSm"}
[2021-02-05 14:24:31] The location is:  -34.1258163, 18.3851121
[2021-02-05 14:24:31] Running Analysis
[2021-02-05 14:24:31] Enviroment Set
[2021-02-05 14:24:31] Starting analysis 601a99a566fd8200113fdcad
```

Comment: This is strange. Are you sure there is no other function with same name i.e. `checkZones `?

Comment: No just checked only one function named checkZones.